# Link to external types in ExDoc

Tags: documentation, elixir, ex-doc

I recently created my first Hex Package; [**Ecto.Rut**](https://github.com/sheharyarn/ecto_rut) and I'm now working on its documentation. Since it uses `Ecto.Repo` at the back and returns `Ecto.Schema` and `Ecto.Changeset` types, I wanted to link them in the @specs.

Internal and Elixir core types (such as `Keyword.t`) are automatically linked, but ex_doc doesn't link external types defined in the Ecto modules. How do I make that happen?

I've currently tried specifying the complete module name in the `@spec` but that doesn't work:

```
@callback all(opts :: Keyword.t) :: [Ecto.Schema.t] | no_return
```

Comment: It's maybe not supported. You can write manually in `@doc` or `@moduledoc` like the following:
https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/a1efd8cc419ff09bd5304349a5fca5245e89094c/lib/phoenix/endpoint.ex#L100

Comment: @ma2gedev It's officially supported as of today.

Comment: @pdimitar wow! nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After [some discussion on ElixirForum](https://elixirforum.com/t/link-to-external-types-in-exdoc/1915/), Jose added this feature. With `ExDoc v0.14.2` and onwards, it supports auto-linking for external dependency modules.

From the [Github Page](https://github.com/elixir-lang/ex_doc):

> By referring to a module, function, type or callback from any of your dependencies, such as `MyDep`, ExDoc will automatically link to that dependency documentation on hexdocs.pm (the link can be configured with the :deps option in your mix.exs)

---

This means, simply mentioning the complete module name would autolink types, callbacks, modules and methods. So, by updating to the latest ExDoc, my existing code now auto-links:

```
@callback all(opts :: Keyword.t) :: [Ecto.Schema.t] | no_return
```